# Why does Source Tree not Git Diff a Powershell Script (ps1)

Tags: git, powershell, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using SourceTree as my git client on Windows (v1.8.3.0).  For some reason it's not showing a `diff` of my PowerShell script (`.ps1`) and instead shows it as a binary:

[image]

Is there a setting I need to toggle to get correct behavior? If I rename the file to be a `.txt` than the `diff` works as expected.

I have a `.gitattributes` file in my repo, and I've updated it to explicitly account for `.ps1` files, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
*.ps1   diff=astextplain
*.PS1   diff=astextplain
```

Alternatively, I can see the `diff` just fine in I goto `External Diff` (via BeyondCompare), however, this doesn't help me craft a commit based of specific line numbers:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue with Atlassian products (BitBucket, SourceTree): https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5453/powershell-module-manifest-file-psd1-are

The issue is my `.ps1` file was saved as UTF16 Unicode.  Changing it to `UTF8` or `ascii` fixes this and I get `diff`s inside of SourceTree again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do (recent git only!)

```
*.ps1 text working-tree-encoding=UTF-16LE eol=CRLF
```

(Remove the LE if with bom etc)

This goes in your [gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file